# how to make a select bar with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, responsive-design, customtkinter

[image: Select bar]

I want to add this select bar design in my code by using tkinter or customtkinter. When I add new habit it should automatically shown in the dashboard page. When I select the added habit I should remove or see the metrics of selected habit.

```
import tkinter
import customtkinter

DARK_MODE = "dark"
customtkinter.set_appearance_mode(DARK_MODE)
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")


class App(customtkinter.CTk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    
        self.title("Change Frames")
        # remove title bar , page reducer and closing page !!!most have a quit button with app.destroy!!! (this app have a quit button so don't worry about that)
        self.overrideredirect(True)
        # make the app as big as the screen (no matter which screen you use) 
        self.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(self.winfo_screenwidth(), self.winfo_screenheight()))
    

        # root!
        self.main_container = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self, corner_radius=10)
        self.main_container.pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=True, padx=10, pady=10)

        # left side panel -> for frame selection
        self.left_side_panel = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self.main_container, width=150, corner_radius=10)
        self.left_side_panel.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT, fill=tkinter.Y, expand=False, padx=5, pady=5)
    
        self.left_side_panel.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.left_side_panel.grid_rowconfigure((0, 1, 2, 3,4), weight=0)
        self.left_side_panel.grid_rowconfigure((5), weight=1)
    
    
        # self.left_side_panel WIDGET
        self.logo_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.left_side_panel, text="Welcome! \n", font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=20, weight="bold"))
        self.logo_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=(20, 10))
    
        self.scaling_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.left_side_panel, text="UI Scaling:", anchor="w")
        self.scaling_label.grid(row=7, column=0, padx=20, pady=(10, 0))
    
        self.scaling_optionemenu = customtkinter.CTkOptionMenu(self.left_side_panel, values=["80%", "90%", "100%", "110%", "120%"],
                                                           command=self.change_scaling_event)
        self.scaling_optionemenu.grid(row=8, column=0, padx=20, pady=(10, 20), sticky = "s")
    
        self.bt_Quit = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.left_side_panel, text="Quit", fg_color= '#EA0000', hover_color = '#B20000', command= self.close_window)
        self.bt_Quit.grid(row=9, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

        # button to select correct frame IN self.left_side_panel WIDGET
        self.bt_edit = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.left_side_panel, text="Add Habit", command=self.add_habit_func)
        self.bt_edit.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

        self.bt_mark_done = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.left_side_panel, text="Mark Done", command=self.mark_done_func)
        self.bt_mark_done.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)
        
        self.bt_add_habit = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.left_side_panel, text="Edit", command=self.edit_func)
        self.bt_add_habit.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

        self.bt_metrics = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.left_side_panel, text="Metrics", command=self.metrics_func)
        self.bt_metrics.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)
        
        self.bt_dash = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.left_side_panel, text="Dashboard", command=self.dash_func)
        self.bt_dash.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)
    

        # right side panel -> have self.right_dashboard inside it
        self.right_side_panel = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self.main_container, corner_radius=10, fg_color="#000811")
        self.right_side_panel.pack(side= "left", fill= tkinter.BOTH, expand=True, padx=5, pady=5)
    
        self.right_dashboard = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self.main_container, corner_radius=10, fg_color="#000811")
        self.right_dashboard.pack(in_=self.right_side_panel, side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=True, padx=0, pady=0)

        
    def dash_func(self):
        self.clear_frame()
        
        self.right_dashboard.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=0)
        self.right_dashboard.grid_columnconfigure((1,3,4,5), weight=1)
        self.right_dashboard.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=2)

    
    #  self.right_dashboard   ----> edit widget  
    def add_habit_func(self):
    
        self.clear_frame()
        #  self.right_left_side_panel   ----> dashboard inside the right side frame 
        self.right_left_side_panel = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self.right_dashboard, width=150, corner_radius=10)
        self.right_left_side_panel.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT, fill=tkinter.Y, expand=False, padx=5, pady=5)
    
        self.right_left_side_panel.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.right_left_side_panel.grid_rowconfigure((0, 1, 2, 3), weight=0)
        self.right_left_side_panel.grid_rowconfigure((4, 5), weight=1)
        
        self.logo_label_edit = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.right_left_side_panel, text="Edit Page! \n", font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=20, weight="bold"))
        self.logo_label_edit.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=(20, 10))
    
        
        self.bt_save = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self.right_left_side_panel, text="Save", command=lambda:print("test statement"))
        self.bt_save.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=20, pady=(100, 0))
        
        
        #  option menü 
        def optionmenu_callback(choice):
            print("optionmenu dropdown clicked:", choice)

        combobox = customtkinter.CTkOptionMenu(master=self.right_left_side_panel,
                                values=["day", "month", "year"],
                                command=optionmenu_callback)
        combobox.grid(row = 3, column = 0, padx=20, pady=(10,0))
        combobox.set("Select Periodicity")  # set initial value
        
        self.bt_cancel = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self.right_left_side_panel, text="Cancel", command=lambda:print("test statement"))
        self.bt_cancel.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=20, pady=(680, 0))
        
        #  self.right_right_side_panel   ----> main inside the right side frame 
        self.right_right_side_panel = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self.right_dashboard, width=1500, corner_radius=10)
        self.right_right_side_panel.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT, fill=tkinter.Y, expand=False, padx=5, pady=5)
        
        self.habit_name_label_edit = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.right_right_side_panel, text="Habit Name \n", font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=20, weight="bold"))
        self.habit_name_label_edit.grid()
        self.habit_name_entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master = self.right_right_side_panel, corner_radius=10, fg_color="black", width = 1500, height = 150)
        self.habit_name_entry.grid(padx = 0, pady = 20)
        
        self.logo_label_edit = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.right_right_side_panel, text="Habit Description \n", font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=20, weight="bold"))
        self.logo_label_edit.grid()
        self.habit_description_entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master = self.right_right_side_panel, corner_radius=10, fg_color="black", width = 1500, height = 150)
        self.habit_description_entry.grid(padx = 0, pady = 20)
        
        self.logo_label_edit = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.right_right_side_panel, text="Goal \n", font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=20, weight="bold"))
        self.logo_label_edit.grid()
        self.goal_entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master = self.right_right_side_panel, corner_radius=10, fg_color="black", width = 1500, height = 150)
        self.goal_entry.grid(padx = 0, pady = 20)
        
    
    #  self.right_dashboard   ----> mark done widget
    def mark_done_func(self):
        self.clear_frame()
        self.bt_save = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self.right_dashboard, text="Save", command=lambda:print("test statement"))
        self.bt_save.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20, pady=(10, 0))
        
        self.bt_cancel = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self.right_dashboard, text="Cancel", command=lambda:print("test statement"))
        self.bt_cancel.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=20, pady=(10, 0))
    #  self.right_dashboard   ----> metrics widget
    def metrics_func(self):
        self.clear_frame()
        self.right_left_side_panel = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self.right_dashboard, width=150, corner_radius=10)
        self.right_left_side_panel.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT, fill=tkinter.Y, expand=False, padx=5, pady=5)
    
       
        
        self.logo_label_metric = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.right_left_side_panel, text="Metrics  \n", font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=20, weight="bold"))
        self.logo_label_metric.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=(20, 10))
    
        
        self.bt_back = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self.right_left_side_panel, text="Back", command=lambda:print("test statement"))
        self.bt_back.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=20, pady=(100, 0))
        #  self.right_right_side_panel   ----> main inside the right side frame   
        self.right_right_side_panel = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self.right_dashboard, width=1500, corner_radius=10)
        self.right_right_side_panel.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT, fill=tkinter.Y, expand=False, padx=5, pady=5)
        
        habit_labels = []
        habit_texts = ["Habit name: ", "Created on: ", "First done on: ", "Last done on: ", "Current Streak: ", "Goal Compliation progress: ", "Longest streak: "]
        
        for text_ in habit_texts:
            label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self.right_right_side_panel, width=1500, height=100, corner_radius=10, text_color="black",fg_color="grey", text=text_, anchor="w")
            label.grid(padx=0, pady=20)
            habit_labels.append(label)
        
    
    def edit_func(self):
        self.clear_frame()
        #  self.right_left_side_panel   ----> dashboard inside the right side frame 
        self.right_left_side_panel = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self.right_dashboard, width=150, corner_radius=10)
        self.right_left_side_panel.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT, fill=tkinter.Y, expand=False, padx=5, pady=5)
    
        self.right_left_side_panel.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.right_left_side_panel.grid_rowconfigure((0, 1, 2, 3), weight=0)
        self.right_left_side_panel.grid_rowconfigure((4, 5), weight=1)
        
        self.logo_label_edit = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.right_left_side_panel, text="Edit Page! \n", font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=20, weight="bold"))
        self.logo_label_edit.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=(20, 10))
    
        
        self.bt_save = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self.right_left_side_panel, text="Save Changes", command=lambda:print("test statement"))
        self.bt_save.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=20, pady=(100, 0))
        
        
        
        
        #  option menü 
        def optionmenu_callback(choice):
            print("optionmenu dropdown clicked:", choice)

        combobox = customtkinter.CTkOptionMenu(master=self.right_left_side_panel,
                                values=["day", "month", "year"],
                                command=optionmenu_callback)
        combobox.grid(row = 3, column = 0, padx=20, pady=(10,0))
        combobox.set("Select Periodicity")  # set initial value
        self.bt_delete = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self.right_left_side_panel, text="Delete", command=lambda:print("test statement"))
        self.bt_delete.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=20, pady=(10, 0))
        
        self.bt_cancel = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self.right_left_side_panel, text="Cancel", command=lambda:print("test statement"))
        self.bt_cancel.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=20, pady=(680, 0))
        
        #  self.right_right_side_panel   ----> main inside the right side frame 
        self.right_right_side_panel = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self.right_dashboard, width=1500, corner_radius=10)
        self.right_right_side_panel.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT, fill=tkinter.Y, expand=False, padx=5, pady=5)
        
        self.habit_name_label_edit = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.right_right_side_panel, text="Habit Name \n", font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=20, weight="bold"))
        self.habit_name_label_edit.grid()
        self.habit_name_entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master = self.right_right_side_panel, corner_radius=10, fg_color="black", width = 1500, height = 150)
        self.habit_name_entry.grid(padx = 0, pady = 20)
        
        self.logo_label_edit = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.right_right_side_panel, text="Habit Description \n", font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=20, weight="bold"))
        self.logo_label_edit.grid()
        self.habit_description_entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master = self.right_right_side_panel, corner_radius=10, fg_color="black", width = 1500, height = 150)
        self.habit_description_entry.grid(padx = 0, pady = 20)
        
        self.logo_label_edit = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.right_right_side_panel, text="Goal \n", font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=20, weight="bold"))
        self.logo_label_edit.grid()
        self.goal_entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master = self.right_right_side_panel, corner_radius=10, fg_color="black", width = 1500, height = 150)
        self.goal_entry.grid(padx = 0, pady = 20)
    # Change scaling of all widget 80% to 120%
    def change_scaling_event(self, new_scaling: str):
        new_scaling_float = int(new_scaling.replace("%", "")) / 100
        customtkinter.set_widget_scaling(new_scaling_float)
    
    
    # close the entire window    
    def close_window(self): 
        App.destroy(self)
        
        
    # CLEAR ALL THE WIDGET FROM self.right_dashboard(frame) BEFORE loading the widget of the concerned page       
    def clear_frame(self):
        for widget in self.right_dashboard.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()


a = App()
a.mainloop()
```

right now my code looks like this. I could not manage to add select bar in dashboard page. Is there anything that I can watch or read online to learn how to do it, or do you have any templates for me to make it happen?